# Fortran 'parameter' type not included in compiled object

Tags: fortran, static-libraries, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a Fortran module that contains some variables that have the attribute `parameter` and some have the attribute `save`. The `parameter` ones are not included in the compiled object, which becomes a problem when trying to assemble a library. For example, consider a file `testModule.f90`:

```
module testMOD
  integer, save :: thisIsSaved = 1
  integer, parameter :: thisIsParametered = 2
end module testMOD
```

I compile this with: `ifort -c testModule.f90`. When I check what's inside it:

```
>$ nm testModule.o
0000000000000000 T testmod._
0000000000000000 D testmod_mp_thisissaved_
```

only the `thisIsSaved` variable is there. I know that I can just change `thisIsParametered` to `save` rather than `parameter` but, ideally, I'd like to prevent a linking user from changing this value. Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:** I'd like this library to be accessible to C codes, as well, not just Fortran.

Answer (score 4):

That should actually be stored in the .mod file.  All of the data types and function prototypes are stored there which is why you need to include it when you send someone a .lib file.  Try linking in the module after using it in something else and it should work just fine.

Essentially the .mod file serves the same purpose as the .h file in c, so of course you are going to have to include it with your library.

[update:]
If you are attempting to use this in C, then as you said, there is no means for you to easily maintain the named constant.  As an alternative, you can use the protected attribute on the entity.  At least with Fortran, anything outside of the module is restricted from writing to the variable.  I don't know if the C compiler and the linker will respect this behavior, but I think this is probably your best shot.

```
module testMOD
 INTEGER, PROTECTED, BIND(C)  :: globalvar = 1
end module testMOD
```

Unfortunately I don't really do much with interoperability with C, so I can't really guarantee that C will respect the protected attribute and not allow the variable to be changed.

Comment: However, if the library is being access from a C code, it's not using the .mod files.

Comment: That is true.  So you want the code to be used by a c compiler as well and still have the parameter available.  I'll have to think on that one.  I'll add something when I come up with it.

Comment: Are you using any of the 2003 language features to make it compatible with c?

Comment: I am using ISO_C_Binding when relevant. This is actually a small part of a larger codebase that needs to link to both C and Fortran codes.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last point. I can change the run-time values of variables from a C program that links to the library.

Comment: The "PROTECTED" attribute is supposed to restrict what code is allowed to change a variable to only that which is within the module the variable is in.  Let me add an example declaration.

Comment: What is the practical difference between `protected` and `parameter` in this case?

Comment: The `protected` attribute allocates this as a variable, whereas `parameter` is a constant, however while it is a variable but the space can't be changed except from within that module.  Thus you could modify it in that module if you changed it with a subroutine in there.  If you had some function or subroutine in the module or perhaps even a type method you could also change the variable as long as the type was declared and allocated within the module.  To the external user of your library, the difference is that it will appear in the object file whereas the `parameter will not.

Comment: Switching to `protected` does include it in the object file, and still prevents it from being modified by a linked Fortan code. For what it's worth, in C I can still change its value.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Since you are grabbing addresses, I wasn't sure how the Fortran compiler could protect it from being written to, unless it used MUTEXes or some other functionality like that.

Comment: I think the only way you could allow write only access would be by using methods (get/set) to protect the access means to private variables.  Not particularly clean with Fortran, I know, but at least you could make a consistent interface that routes C and Fortran through Fortran interface code which respects restrictions.  I'm not sure how you can protect against anything really when C is in the mix.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, a parameter is a named constant and implementations may not set aside storage for that constant in the object code (particularly for scalars).

Your library should provide a header file for your C clients.  You can define the value of the Fortran parameter in that header file, either by #define or const.

This requires maintenance of the value of the parameter in two places, but you already have that maintenance burden with other aspects of the library's interface.

Comment: I already have the headers, but they just have something like `extern "C" int testmod_mp_thisissaved_`. I suppose I can tinker with my makefile to have it populate the values these in the header file.

Comment: Use BIND(C) on your module variables and directly specify their C name.  Don't use the Fortran processor's mangled name - that's a recipe for a portability and maintenance nightmare.  ifort's module name mangling changes with compile optipns and perhaps compiler version - let alone the changes that might happen moving to a completely different processor.

Comment: Will using `bind(C)` affect how Fortran codes interact with the library?

Comment: For variables - beyond a recompile (the attribute will change the name used by the linker) - no.  For procedures - they must have an explicit interface (noting module procedures automatically have an explicit interface).  For both cases (procedures and variables) the BIND(C) attribute imposes additional requirements (constraints) on the thing being declared/defined, but typically if you want something to be interoperable you'd already be meeting those constraints - e.g. the companion C compiler to a F2008 processor won't have a clue about Fortran pointers, allocatables, etc.