# Accessing Fortran module PARAMETER from python using ctypes

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

Assume I have a module which looks like

```
MODULE test_module
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: var1 = 25
    INTEGER :: var2
    REAL, DIMENSION(var1) :: arr1
END MODULE test_module
```

I compile with this

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so test_module.f90
```

And I check the shared object and it does not contain var1

```
nm libtest.so | grep test_module
0000000000200e00 B __test_module_MOD_arr1
0000000000200e64 B __test_module_MOD_var2
```

Now in python I can load the shared object and access `var2`:

```
import ctypes

lib=ctypes.CDLL("./libtest.so")
ftemp = ctypes.c_int
var2 = ftemp.in_dll(lib,'__test_module_MOD_var2')
```

How do I access `VAR1` in the module?

Comment: So the takeaway from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694796/fortran-parameter-type-not-included-in-compiled-object is that the variable should be typed `INTEGER, PARAMETER, BIND(C) :: var1=25` to be visible in the shared object.

Comment: You can't have `bind` and `parameter` attributes on the same entity. What you can do, though, is `integer, bind(c) :: export_var1=var1`, say.  In some ways that's better: you get to avoid the Fortran module entity name mangling.

Comment: So there's no way to directly access the value of a Fortran entity with the PARAMETER attribute through a shared object?  I guess I could write a wrapper function in Fortran which returns the values of the entities typed as PARAMETER.

Comment: Correct, at least "portably" (this is all implementation-specific really).  There's no need for named constants to exist beyond compilation.